# Writing A Program that clicks a Chrome alert box

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, event-listener

I have an alert that comes up in chrome, it slides into the browser on the top right hand side of the window. Every time this specific alert comes up I have to move my mouse over and click the alert box which will then open up a link in a new window. I have to do this multiple times a day. I'd be great if I could write a Javascript or Python program that will automatically "click" the box every time it comes up in the browser. Is there a way to do this? I have a little over a year of programming experience but I don't expect a step by step answer, just set me off in the right direction. I've looked up browser events hoping I could just write an event listener function but I couldn't find one specifically for browser alerts.

Comment: Is this an actual alert call or just a separate modal/dialog box that slides in to give you notifications?

Answer (score 1):

If it is the native modal of the browser, then the short answer is no.
You can't do it with `javascript` as the confirm (alert) pop up is a blocking modal.
No `javascript` code can run while the confirm modal is open.

If this is a custom modal that built and controlled by javascript then there is a good chance of doing just about anything you want with it.

Comment: It could be just me but I think that was poor wording. I don't think it's actually an alert call just a separate modal

Comment: if this is the case then of course it is doable :) either way i will update my answer to be more clear. thanks

Comment: Okay, that's awesome. Thanks for the thoughts. It's the same kind of pop up that comes up for any generic alert through the chrome browser. That would indicate that it is a native modal of the browser so I guess I'm out of luck here.